# How to change from keyboard events to mouse events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, visual-studio-macros

The code below been programmed to do keyboard event's listening, but I want to change it to listen to mouse buttons. For example, Instead of feeding fast with Q I want it to be with right mouse button, instead of split with space I want it to be with left mouse button, Can anyone help?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Best Tricksplit, Doublesplit, and Feeding Macros + Auto Settings + Triplesplit Macro
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.9
// @description  Sets show mass and dark theme to true, provides a tricksplit with E or 4, triplesplit with 3, doublesplit with D or 2, faster feeding with Q, and split with 1
// @author       Jack Burch + Tom Burris
// @match        http://abs0rb.me/*
// @match        http://agar.io/*
// @match        http://agarabi.com/*
// @match        http://agarly.com/*
// @match        http://en.agar.bio/*
// @match        http://agar.pro/*
// @match        http://agar.biz/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==
window.addEventListener('keydown', keydown);
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyup);
var Feed = false;
var Dingus = false;
var imlost = 25;
load();

function keydown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 81) {
        Feed = true;
        setTimeout(F, imlost);
    } // Tricksplit
    if (event.keyCode == 16) { 
        i();
        setTimeout(i, imlost);
        setTimeout(i, imlost*2);
        setTimeout(i, imlost*3);
          }  // Doublesplit
    if (event.keyCode == 18 ) {
        i();
       setTimeout(i, imlost);
    }// Split
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        i();
   }
} // When Player left Q, It Stop Feeding fast
function keyup(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 81) {
        Feed = false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 79) {
        Dingus = false;
    }
}
// Feed Macro With Q 
function F() {
    if (Feed) {
        window.onkeydown({keyCode: 87});
        window.onkeyup({keyCode: 87});
        setTimeout(F, imlost);
    }
}
function i() {
    $("body").trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 32}));
    $("body").trigger($.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 32}));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few research and help from my friend i find the code should be change to be like shown below

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         saqar
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.9
// @description  Sets show mass and dark theme to true, provides a tricksplit with E or 4, triplesplit with 3, doublesplit with D or 2,                  faster feeding with Q, and split with 1
// @author       Jack Burch + Tom Burris
// @match        http://abs0rb.me/*
// @match        http://3rb.be/*
// @match        http://agar.io/*
// @match        http://agarabi.com/*
// @match        http://cell.sh/*
// @match        http://agarly.com/*
// @match        http://en.agar.bio/*
// @match        http://agar.pro/*
// @match        http://agar.biz/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('keydown', keydown);
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyup);
window.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', discm);
var Feed = false;
var Dingus = false;
var imlost = 25;
load();

function keydown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 81) {
        Feed = true;
        setTimeout(F, imlost);
    } // Tricksplit
    if (event.keyCode == 16) { 
        i();
        setTimeout(i, imlost);
        setTimeout(i, imlost*2);
        setTimeout(i, imlost*3);
        setTimeout(i, imlost*4);
          }  // Doublesplit
    if (event.keyCode == 18 ) {
        i();
       setTimeout(i, imlost);
    }// Split
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        i();
   }
} // When Player left Q, It Stop Feeding fast
function keyup(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 81) {
        Feed = false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 79) {
        Dingus = false;
    }
}
// Split with left mouse btn
function mousedown(event) {
    if (event.which == 1) i();
    else if (event.which == 3) {
        Feed = true;
        setTimeout(F, imlost);
    }
}
// Feed macro with right mouse btn
function mouseup(event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        Feed = false;
    }
}
// Disable context menu
function discm(e) {
    if (!$('input').is(':focus')) e.preventDefault();
}
// Feed Macro With Q 
function F() {
    if (Feed) {
        window.onkeydown({keyCode: 87});
        window.onkeyup({keyCode: 87});
        setTimeout(F, imlost);
    }
}
function i() {
    $("body").trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 32}));
    $("body").trigger($.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 32}));
}
```